# Crash when redirecting stdout to stderr for a second time

Tags: rust, stdout, stderr, unsafe

The second run of `foo()` will crash without an error message. When I remove this `unsafe` line, it works ok.

```
use std::process::{Command, Stdio};
use std::os::unix::io::FromRawFd;

fn foo() {
    let mut p = Command::new("ls");
    unsafe { p.stdout(Stdio::from_raw_fd(2)) };
    let mut child = p.spawn().expect("spawn error");
    child.wait().expect("wait error");
    println!("process: {:?}", p);
}

fn main() {
    foo();
    foo();
}
```

1. It seems the `unsafe` code here has some issue. Maybe it's not releasing some resource?
2. Is there a way to do the stdout -> stderr redirection without using unsafe code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Stdio::from_raw_fd(2)` gives ownership of file descriptor 2 to the newly constructed `Stdio` object. `Stdio`'s destructor will close the file descriptor. `Stdio`'s destructor will run when the `Command` is dropped, because the `Command` owns the `Stdio`.

Of course, the reason you're not getting any output on the second call to `foo` is that standard error has been closed!

The simple solution would be to duplicate file descriptor 2 and pass the duplicate to `Stdio::from_raw_fd`.

Comment: The ownership semantics of this `unsafe` code is [clearly documented](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/os/unix/io/trait.FromRawFd.html#tymethod.from_raw_fd). OP would be well-served by **completely reading** the documentation for any `unsafe` code they use.

Comment: @Francis thanks! `libc::dup()` works here! @Shepmaster thanks for pointing this out, you're right ;)